# rgbdslam depth data using asus xtion PRO

Tags: slam, navigation, openni, asus-xtion-pro-live, camera-depth-points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is the data obtained from asus xtion pro using rgbdslam in meters??
i kept the object against a wall whch is 3m away, But i am not able to make sense of the depth values for the scene in the PCD file,

the depth value fluctuates between -1 to 3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173486/rgbdslam-depth-data-using-asus-xtion-pro/) by [SangeethaKrishnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/18853/sangeethakrishnan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is in meter, but the values in the pcd files are the xyz coordinates with respect to the origin of the global coordinate system (which is the first frame you capture), not the depth.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0